# Javascript HTTPS-Frame Access to Parent HTTP-Frame

Tags: javascript, html, cross-domain, xss, same-origin-policy

How can an IFRAME with URL `https://domain/` access the DOM of the parent frame which has URL `http://domain/` (HTTPS calls HTTP)?

**Both frames will cooperate.** The domain is the same in both frames, just the **protocol is different**. Setting `document.domain` is not allowed as that would allow for XSS attacks coming from other untrusted frames.

As an alternative to accessing the DOM it would be enough to send a message (containing a single integer). Notice, that the `postMessage` API only works in IE8+. I need **IE6+**.

Answer (score 1):

Is easyXDM an option. It supports postMessage for browsers with support, and falls back to other mechanisms for older browsers. Some of the mechanisms are a bit hacky but they work.

But why do you want to have a secure iframe on an insecure page?

Comment: The outer frame being HTTP is a given for us but it is trusted by us. The iframe being HTTPS is because the user can post sensitive data. I'll look into easyXDM, thanks.

Comment: Still, if you are on an open wireless or similar, an attacker can inject data into the http page (see for instance sslstrip) and reduce the security of the site.

Comment: Good point but the iframe's server makes sure it is only being called over HTTPS.

Comment: Attacker changes the iframe's src location to http:/ /evil.com/proxy?url=https:/ /real/location
Because the victim does not see the url of the iframe in the URL bar, nothings seems wrong. The contents show as expected as well, only they are not genuine.

Comment: Nice attack ;-) Ok that would work but we don't care about that attack. At this point, security is secondary (with the exception that the iframe uses HTTPS to cover the most likely attack scenarios).

Comment: Ok. Just thought I'd mention it.